\mathsf{} not working when used in \rl{}
I want to write a function with digits in Persian, I used XePersian package and it worked well(I mean that 2 will be shown in Persian) when I used like the following:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale = 1.0 ,
        BoldFont = *Bd ,
        ItalicFont = *It ,
        BoldItalicFont = *BdIt ,
        Extension = .ttf
        ]{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[]{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfdigitfont[Scale = 1.0 ,
         BoldFont = *Bd ,
         ItalicFont = *It ,
         BoldItalicFont = *BdIt ,
         Extension = .ttf
         ]{XB Niloofar} 
\begin{document}
$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $\\
\end{document}


But when I want to use the function between some Persian texts, It does not work well
(I mean that 2 will not shown in Persian):
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale = 1.0 ,
        BoldFont = *Bd ,
        ItalicFont = *It ,
        BoldItalicFont = *BdIt ,
        Extension = .ttf
        ]{XB Niloofar}
\setlatintextfont[]{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfdigitfont[Scale = 1.0 ,
         BoldFont = *Bd ,
         ItalicFont = *It ,
         BoldItalicFont = *BdIt ,
         Extension = .ttf
         ]{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
\rl{نمودار مشتق تابع}
\lr{$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $}
\rl{را رسم کنید}
\end{document}


Here I want the number 2 in power to be shown like above.
Please help me fixing this problem.
Thank for your time.

Welcome! Is the problem font-specific or can this be reproduced with fonts from a standard TeX Live, for example? I don't have any of the fonts you use, so I can't test whether I can reproduce the problem or not. Only Windows users usually have Times New Roman, for example - never mind the Persian fonts.

@cfr: Thank you, I made an editing and hope it makes my question better.

Not sure why you used \lr{} for the formula because without the LTR environment, the formula looks perfectly fine. Here is what I have:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[
    UprightFont=*-ExtraLight,
    BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-Medium]{Vazirmatn}

\setlatintextfont{Times}

\setmathdigitfont[
    UprightFont=*-ExtraLight,
    BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-Medium]{Vazirmatn}


\setmathsfdigitfont[
    UprightFont=*-ExtraLight,
    BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-Medium]{Vazirmatn}

\begin{document}

\begin{persian}

$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $\\

نمودار مشتق تابع
$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $
را رسم کنید

\end{persian}

\end{document}

and it looks perfectly fine:

But in case you really have to use the LTR environment, you can use it but then you need to specifically set the math digits to Persian. To do so, you need to have \PersianMathDigits in your code. By default, \AutoMathDigits is used which changes the digits based on the environment. Here is the same example but with this option:
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[
    UprightFont=*-ExtraLight,
    BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-Medium]{Vazirmatn}

\setlatintextfont{Times}

\setmathdigitfont[
    UprightFont=*-ExtraLight,
    BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-Medium]{Vazirmatn}


\setmathsfdigitfont[
    UprightFont=*-ExtraLight,
    BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont=*-Medium]{Vazirmatn}

\begin{document}

\begin{persian}

\PersianMathDigits

$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $\\

نمودار مشتق تابع
\lr{$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $}
را رسم کنید

\AutoMathDigits

$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $\\

نمودار مشتق تابع
\lr{$f(x) = x^{\mathsf{2}} + \ln{x}\ $}
را رسم کنید

\end{persian}

\end{document}

You can see how changing the math digit option changes the behavior:

